# What is an element of an iterated tangent bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, terminology

An element of the tangent bundle $T M$ of a manifold is called a "(tangent) vector".  An element of its dual $T^* M$ is called a "covector" or a "1-form".  An element of the exterior square $\Lambda^2(T M)$ is called a "bivector", and an element of $\Lambda^2(T^*M)$ is called a "2-form".  More generally, elements of the various tensor powers of $T M$ and $T^*M$ are called "tensors".

Is there a name for an element of an iterated tangent bundle $T^k M = T(T(\cdots (T M)))$?

Comment: I'd call them something like "n-fold variations".

Comment: Shouldn't we reserve $1$-form to mean a global section of $T^{\ast}$ rather than a point in its total space?

Comment: I'm tempted to call the elements of T^2M accelerations, but no idea for the higher $k$...

Comment: Whatever name you choose, it shouldn't allow confusion with elements of higher-order tangent bundles (as opposed to iterated ones).

Comment: @Qiaochu: people already use the term 1-form for elements of a dual vector space, so global section or not, the terminology is in use.  And Paul: what's the distinction between higher-order and iterated tangent bundles?

Comment: @Ryan, e.g. the second order tangent bundle of $\mathcal{M}$ is the vector bundle over $\mathcal{M}$ whose fibre at $p$ consists of $2$-jets at $p$ of curves through $p$. It has rank $n(n+1)/2$ for $n = dim \mathcal{M}$. Just as for the first order tangent bundle, there is also an algebraic definition if you are so minded.

Comment: @PaulReynolds is the second order tangent bundle really a *vector* bundle?  I thought that it wasn't (even though each fiber is a vector space) since jets don't transform like vectors.

Comment: FWIW, if we have to invent a name, the best I've thought of so far is "flare" -- like a jet, but less unidirectional.

Comment: **Certain** sections of the double tangent bundle $TTM$ are called *sprays*; check Wikipedia.

Comment: @ClaudioGorodski right, but I don't think that helps because sprays have to satisfy an additional condition (plus they are sections rather than points).

Comment: @MikeShulman isn't the iterated tangent bundle $\mathrm{TT}M$ representable in SDG by $D\times D$? In this case maybe its elements should be called microsquares?

Comment: @Arrow Sure, that would work at least for an audience familiar with SDG.  And I suppose everyone at least has the intuition of a tangent vector as a "microsegment", even if they don't know how to make it precise.

Answer (score 5):

I called them "expansion" because they act on functions on $M$ by (Taylor) expanding them.
This is a generalization of derivation. 
See 37.6 of

- Ivan Kolár, Jan Slovák, Peter W. Michor: Natural operations in differential geometry. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, (1993) [pdf](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf).

Perhaps you need to skim the whole chapter VIII.